# GPO vs attributes for users exctracting using CSVDE

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, users

I am currently in doubt about how the GPO is changing the attributes of the users registered in the AD.

I have a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and I have a few **active** users that have the flag "PASSWD_NOTRQ". When I asked about this, one of the system administrators told me that the GPO overrules this setting and actually those users do not present a security risk. I extracted those users using the CSVDE command on the server.

How can it be that the attributes of users "are overruled by the GPO", but when I extract them, they appear to not have a password required to login?

Comment: I don't know what "overruled by GPO" means in this case, but if your admin suggests that the GPO password policy negates these entries, he is probably wrong.

Comment: GPOs do not (aside from calling a script that may do so) affect the properties or attributes of accounts in Active Directory.  An account that does not have a password required does not have a password required.  End of story.  However, as long as ACLs and local User Rights are configured to require at least "Authenticated Users" then these accounts would be unable to access said resources - but that only limits the risk, it doesn't remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Semicolon. I will take a deeper dive into the problem and check what those GPOs do on the system. I also though that it is quite strange that I can extract active users without a password required